# Rhino Mocks - Use Expect.Call for a method with two signatures

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, rhino-mocks

How can I mock a method with two signatures?

sudo code:

```
public Class ClassA{
  //... do stuff
}

public Class ClassB{
  //... do stuff
}

public Class BigClass
{
  public BigClass(){}

  public ClassB MapMe(ClassA a)
  {
     //... do stuff
     return new ClassB();
  }

  public ClassA MapMe(ClassB a)  
  {
     //... do stuff    
     return new ClassA();
  }
}

public Class ClassToTest
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
     var ResultA = BigClass.MapMe(new ClassA());

     //... do some more stuff

     ResultA = BigClass.MapMe(new ClassB());
  }
}
```

Apologies for the poor code example, doing this on IPad, but hopefully gives you the idea.

Comment: It's not clear why the obvious answer isn't just "the same way you mock a class with one signature" (or ideally an interface, of course). I suggest you delete this question, then wait until you're at a computer where you can really write a *good* question, with a proper example, showing what you've tried and what happened.

Comment: grumpy, guess I should stick to LinkedIn developers forum people seem to be able to understand that in hotel rooms, you may only have your memory and an iPad.

Comment: But in that case, is it so incredibly urgent that you get an answer right now? You can't test or use it anyway - so why not be considerate to people who are trying to answer the question, and wait until you've got time to do it properly? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [Argument Constraints](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino%20Mocks%203.5.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#ArgumentConstraints)

> Argument constraints also define the method's signature by specifying
>   the arguments types. That's why they can't be omitted.

```
mock.Expect(x => x.MapMe(Arg<ClassB>.Is.Anything).Return(resultB);
mock.Expect(x => x.MapMe(Arg<ClassA>.Is.Anything).Return(resultA);
```

## EDIT:

I believe an other issue you faced - you've mocked `BigClass` without backing interface so obviously RhinoMocks does not allow setting expectations on such a mock. So just abstract a `BigClass` by interface and mock based on it:

```
public interface IMapper
{
    ClassB MapMe(ClassA entity);
    ClassA MapMe(ClassB entity);
}

public class BigClass : IMapper


[Test]
public void MapperTest()
{
    // !!! Below I've used WhenCalled() to show you that correct  
    // expectation is called based on argument type, just see in debugger
    IMapper mapperMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMapper>();
    mapperMock.Expect(x => x.MapMe(Arg<ClassA>.Is.Anything))
              .WhenCalled((mi) =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("MapMe - ClassA parameter");
                        })
              .Return(null /*TODO: return correct instance*/);
    mapperMock.Expect(x => x.MapMe(Arg<ClassB>.Is.Anything))
              .WhenCalled((mi) =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("MapMe - ClassB parameter");
                        })
              .Return(null /*TODO: return correct instance*/);

    var resultB = mapperMock.MapMe(new ClassA());
    var resultA = mapperMock.MapMe(new ClassB());

   // TODO: Asserts
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, should have said that I tried this and it failed, can't remember the error just now, but will add it when I get to work in the morning.

Comment: also tried a few other, will add these in the morning too, save repeating the tested ways.  Can't remember exactly where the error was, but think it wa in the replayAll.

Comment: I believe you mocked class without backing interface, see updated answer. Anyway please add actual code you re using since it is hard to assume

Comment: Many thanks, hadn't thought about using WhenCalled, will give it a go, but definitely a way forward.  BTW please assume that the dummy classes have interfaces, I just haven't put them on there. also using ForGeneric.Create<ClassA, ClassB>().Create;

Comment: I've used WhenCalled() just to illustrate that correct expectation was called, but tou can just use `Expect(..).Return(..)` as I've initially did

Comment: back in the hotel room and catching up with other stuff.  Won't put code here, iPad just isn't the thing to use here for that.  But needless to say, the corporate wasn't the mock, but in fact the code.  There was a hidden initialiser in a #region which I didn't check.  I didnt write the code, but should have done a full review before writing the test.  My bad!  thanks for the help